# Setup smooch-js with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, smooch

I followed [Smooch](https://smooch.io/) [instructions](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-js#usage) with no success.

Here is the minimal code that fails for me:

```
<!doctype html><html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.2.0/require.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        require.config({
            "paths": {
                "smooch": "https://cdn.smooch.io/smooch.min"
            }
        });
        // Tried this
        require(["require", "smooch"], function(require){
            var Smooch = require("smooch");
            console.log(Smooch);  // → undefined
        });
        // Tried that
        require(["smooch"], function(Smooch){
            console.log(Smooch);  // → undefined
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

`require` returns me an `undefined` so no `Smooch.init(...)` for me. Tested in both Firefox and Chrome.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use "Smooch" instead of "smooch" in your require calls, like this :

```
<!doctype html><html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.2.0/require.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        require.config({
            "paths": {
                "Smooch": "https://cdn.smooch.io/smooch.min"
            }
        });
        // Tried this
        require(["require", "Smooch"], function(require){
            var Smooch = require("Smooch");
            console.log(Smooch);  // → Smooch object
        });
        // Tried that
        require(["Smooch"], function(Smooch){
            console.log(Smooch);  // → Smooch object
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

The lib is wrapped in a UMD wrapper and self-defines its name to be "Smooch".

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed it fixed the issue. I think I had tried `Smooch` instead of `smooch` but I must have had something else broken at that point and then reverted to what the readme said.

Comment: No problem! We will update the documentation to explain this better.